# ConvergenceError: The model did not converge. Try adding a larger penalizer to see if that helps convergence

Tags: python, pandas, lifetimes-python

I tried the following code from the lifetimes library, using a 1 million row dataset. I get the error "ConvergenceError:  The model did not converge. Try adding a larger penalizer to see if that helps convergence." I havent set any penalizer.

```
 bgf.fit(summary_cal_holdout['frequency_cal'], 
        summary_cal_holdout['recency_cal'], 
        summary_cal_holdout['T_cal'])

 fun: -0.6687805030754939
 hess_inv: array([[3.59401922e+00, 4.07817298e+00, 1.96553220e-04, 3.81178105e-01],
       [4.07817298e+00, 7.68848347e+00, 2.57679876e-04, 3.33282620e+00],
       [1.96553220e-04, 2.57679876e-04, 7.65922646e+01, 7.65930375e+01],
       [3.81178107e-01, 3.33282620e+00, 7.65930375e+01, 1.05547305e+02]])
      jac: array([ 5.54469203e-07, -1.18094006e-07, -6.14083829e-08,  6.21662541e-08])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 87
      nit: 42
     njev: 76
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([-0.60365091, -1.75150201, 12.07528864, 14.80580897])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConvergenceError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28924\3528314986.py in <module>
----> 1 bgf.fit(summary_cal_holdout['frequency_cal'], 
      2         summary_cal_holdout['recency_cal'],
      3         summary_cal_holdout['T_cal'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifetimes\fitters\beta_geo_fitter.py in fit(self, frequency, recency, T, weights, initial_params, verbose, tol, index, **kwargs)
    135         scaled_T = T * self._scale
    136 
--> 137         log_params_, self._negative_log_likelihood_, self._hessian_ = self._fit(
    138             (frequency, scaled_recency, scaled_T, weights, self.penalizer_coef),
    139             initial_params,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lifetimes\fitters\__init__.py in _fit(self, minimizing_function_args, initial_params, params_size, disp, tol, bounds, **kwargs)
    113             return output.x, output.fun, hessian_
    114         print(output)
--> 115         raise ConvergenceError(
    116             dedent(
    117                 """

ConvergenceError: 
The model did not converge. Try adding a larger penalizer to see if that helps convergence.
```

Answer (score 0):

Before fitting the model you need to define the bgf model that will be used. The penalizer_coef has a default value of 0.0:

```py
bgf = BetaGeoFitter(penalizer_coef=0.0)
bgf.fit(summary_cal_holdout['frequency_cal'],
        summary_cal_holdout['recency_cal'], 
        summary_cal_holdout['T_cal'])
```

From the lifetimes [documentation](https://lifetimes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.fitters.html#lifetimes.fitters.beta_geo_beta_binom_fitter.BetaGeoBetaBinomFitter):

> In typical applications, penalizers on the order of 0.001 to 0.1 are effective.

Change the penalizer coeficient to 0.01 first and check convergence. If not, make the value bigger until the fitting converges.

Comment: If possible, please be clear instead of "try" : What line of code would help change this value? Maybe a suggested value or order of magnitude, as a starting guess?